# Are all אוזני המן halachically equal?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Is it permissible for a shul to serve אוזני המן (Hamantaschen) without including poppy seed or chocolate ones?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: dfeuer, Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thank you for bringing this crucial question to our attention. Please note that regardless of what you learn here, you should consult your pastry chef before making any rash decisions. I hope you'll check out some of our other [tag:purim-torah-in-jest] content, and while you're at it, maybe also some of the [real stuff](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim).

Comment: Chocolate hamantashen are an abomination unto Nuggan. Poppy is ideal of course; lekvár quite acceptable; and apricot & raspberry only _b’sha‘as had’chak_.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the shul is required to serve chocolate ones. You must be kidding. They really make chocolate ones now? You mean chocolate dipped / covered, or chocolate filling? I haven't seen this. Where have I been?

Poppy seed ones are an absolute must. The reason? It is called *mohn* in Yiddish. And how can you serve Hamantaschen that don't have ha-*mohn*?

Comment: I man filled with chocolate chips that partially melt in the oven and then solidify. They can also be combined with apricot jam.

Comment: @dfeuer - Ah! I have heard of the choco chip idea. I now that's become trendy. To me it's an embarrassment even to Haman :-)

Comment: +1 cause we live in a crazy society where people, YIDDEN!, don't like poppy filling.  Can you imagine?! Frowning in disgust at mokash cake or poppy hamentashen?! Unbelievable.

Comment: @user6591 - I'm still somewhat at the end of my drunken stupor and am happy. Don't get me started on what youth do and don't do these days. Mohn is healthier. Now, they say, "oh no. we can't eat poppy seeds because it will appear in a urine sample and then I can't work for the CIA!"